# how to fix "'Error:BrokenCount>0'" after a failed attempt to install virtualbox-5.1

Tags: virtualbox, dependencies

"An error occurred.Please run the Package Manger form the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.The error message was:'Error:BrokenCount>0'.This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies."
the software center is showing virtualBox 5.1 and saying: " fail to satisfy all dependencies ( broken cache), i red the posts relevant to this error but didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I see this kind of problems most often when my apt databases are pointing to older versions of package files that have since been removed, so cannot be downloaded anymore.

If this is not already the solution then the `apt-get -f` give you some more output that points into the direction of the cause for this problem.